# Why is there no "13" hive in SharePoint Server?

Tags: 2007

I know it's not hugely technical, but did anyone ever get an answer to why there is no "13" hive in SharePoint.  Does the old superstition still reign supreme? Or was there a Beta version somewhere between 2007 and 2010.  Did Microsoft ever make a statement on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen a statement, but assumed it was related to the superstition (e.g. no building 13 on Redmond campus).  There was no beta between 2007 and 2010.  Will be interesting to see if any products launch in 2013, right.

Comment: Did not know about the no 13th building on the Microsoft campus either, I would likley assume the tradition is it then

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft decided to skip the entire v13 for the Office line.  So Office 2010 is version 14.

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/ButWhy/There-is-no-Office-13-But-Why/

Related, the 12-hive in SP2010 is the 14-hive, but the generalized name is SharePoint Root.